# Angular 8 Jasmine not matching HTTP request

Tags: angular, jasmine, mocking, httptestingcontroller

I have an Angular service making some HTTP requests, and I want to test that it's making them the right way.

Among its dependencies, it also has an `EnvironmentService` that returns the correct API endpoints according to the environment, that I have mocked with Jasmine.

My test looks like this:

```
describe('ShipmentsService', () => {

    let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;
    let service: ShipmentsService;
    const envSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('EnvironmentService', ['getRestEndpoint', 'dev']);

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                ShipmentsService,
                {provide: EnvironmentService, useValue: envSpy}
            ],
            imports: [HttpClientTestingModule]
        });

        httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
        service = TestBed.get(ShipmentsService);
    });

    it('does the right HTTP request', () => {
        envSpy.getRestEndpoint.and.returnValue('foo');
        service.doStuff(123);
        expect(envSpy.getRestEndpoint)
            .toHaveBeenCalledWith('changePackingProperties');

        const request = httpTestingController.expectOne('foo');
        request.flush({shipmentId: 123});
        httpTestingController.verify();    
    });
});
```

And here is my `ShipmentsService` method:

```
doStuff(shipmentId: number) {
    let path = this.environmentService.getRestEndpoint('changePackingProperties');
    return this.http.post(path, body, {headers}).pipe(map(
      (response) => response
    ));
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was missing was that my service method was indeed returning an `Observable`, so for it to be completed the test needed to be `subscribe`d to it.

TO make the test work, then, the actual service call needed to be

```
service.doStuff(123).subscribe(() => {});
```